# heap size of different element

Tags: java, android, memory-management, android-lifecycle

Have such question about usage different element of my project.
First of all few word about my project: this is a presentation with game element, i have about 18 activities. Each activity has own layout with a few element which animated by xml animation.
And all of this "slides" must shown roundly.
Actually this model very well work on galaxy tab 2 (Android 4.1), but also i must use it on old galaxy tab(android 2.2) and on this device my program crashing after few rounds of showing.
First of all  for old version of my device i delete some animation , all java class after intent startActivity trying different method like finish(); super.onDestroy(); but this operation helps me decrease usage of heap memory and life cycle of program little bit increasing(but problem don't solving), large heap tag don't work , and also in manifest i use noMemory tag, for all activity.

Structure of my layout: absolute layout on which i situate my picture and additional layout for swipe realization.

So, can you help(say how to) increasing life cycle of my program?

Comment: You can try doing a memory analysis using MAT or some other tool ?

Comment: Have you confirmed that the crash is caused by an `OutOfMemoryError` or could it be some other error?

Comment: Use log, and fined it VM heap error , it cant allocate some part of memory

Comment: I suggest you profile your application and see what it is using most of its memory for, and reduce it.

Comment: do you download it ???